# find the cyclic shift of the given string

Tags: php

I have to do the cyclic shift of the string. For example if I have string "hihi"
I have to find the cyclic shift

```
"hihi" is 0th shift of "hihi"
"ihih" is 1st shift of "hihi"
"hihi" is 2nd 
"ihih" is 3rd
```

In this case "hihi" is repeated twice so it has two cyclic shift.

Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do a combination of array shifts and array to string operations:

```
function shift($string) {
    $arr = str_split($string);
    $head = array_shift($arr);
    array_push($arr,$head); 
    return implode($arr);
}   

$str = "hihi";
$shifts = strlen($str); //n shifts (incl. original)
for ($i = 0;$i < $shifts;$i++) {
     echo $str.PHP_EOL;
     $str = shift($str);  
}
```

Check it out at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49e5ef01f3cc49db7c353f8ab8d74322375c4d22